# How can I shoehorn a regular file descriptor into zmq::poller_t (specifically using cppzmq)?

Tags: zeromq

I've got some existing code that uses `template<typename t = no_user_data> class poller_t` from cppzmq.  It's actually instantiated with `t` being `int`, not that it matters.

In libzmq, there is a method `zmq_poller_add_fd(void *, int, void *, short)` that would allow me to wait on a regular file descriptor as well as the zmq::socket_t objects that are already being used.

I need to add a regular file descriptor to the `wait_all` of the poller_t object, but unfortunately, I can't see an equivalent feature (equivalent to `zmq_poller_add_fd`) in cppzmq.

What approaches have people used to get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that it can't be done using cppzmq facilities, but you can write your own implementation of the poller_t class, because it's FOSS, and just extend it with the additional features that you need.  It works a charm.

The starting point is to copy your version of the implementation of the `poller_t` template class into a new header file, and then just add the following in the appropriate locations.  You may need to make slight modifications to suit, depending on how the cppzmq library evolves.  Use `using` declarations to bring the necessary types into your namespace.

```
    template<
      typename Dummy = void,
      typename =
        typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<T, no_user_data>::value, Dummy>::type>
    void add(int fd, event_flags events, T *user_data)
    {
        add_fd_impl(fd, events, user_data);
    }

    void add(int fd, event_flags events)
    {
        add_fd_impl(fd, events, nullptr);
    }

    void remove(int fd)
    {
        if (0 != zmq_poller_remove_fd(poller_ptr.get(), fd)) {
            throw error_t();
        }
    }

    void modify(int fd, event_flags events)
    {
        if (0
            != zmq_poller_modify_fd(poller_ptr.get(), fd,
                                 static_cast<short>(events))) {
            throw error_t();
        }
    }


    void add_fd_impl(int fd, event_flags events, T *user_data)
    {
        if (0
            != zmq_poller_add_fd(poller_ptr.get(), fd, user_data,
                              static_cast<short>(events))) {
            throw error_t();
        }
    }
```